# Chrome extension background script into multiple scripts - manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Google Chrome extensions before manifest v3 I could divide **background.js** into multiple scripts. And to load all scripts to be visible in **background.js** I only need to to put them in array in manifest like this:

```
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["helpers/countHelper.js", "helpers/networkHelper.js", "background/main.js"],
}
```

With this above sintax, all scripts will be merged into one file.

Now in documentation how to use manifest v3, they wrote:

> Replace background.page or background.scripts with
> background.service_worker in manifest.json. Note that the
> service_worker field takes a string, not an array of string.

Cause background in manifest can't take multiple scripts, how to divide background script into multiple scripts.
Also **import** syntax is not allowed as I know.

Answer (score 13):

> With this above sintax, all scripts will be merged into one file.

It is not true, but let's fly over...

You can use **importScript** but not in manifest.
Look at this template:

```
/* V3 manifest.json */
"background": {
    "service_worker": "worker_wrapper.js"
},

/* worker_wrapper.js */
try {
    importScripts("helpers/countHelper.js", "helpers/networkHelper.js", "background/main.js");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

<del>Bear in mind that SW file must be placed in root folder</del>, whereas other scripts could be placed in other folders

Comment: I am getting the error TypeError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Module scripts don't support importScripts().
    at background.ts:3:5

Comment: @rbansal Make sure to remove in the manifest file "type: module" from the background service_worker. Then it works.

Comment: "Bear in mind that SW file must be placed in root folder" . why is that? Is it like a requirement of MV3 ?

Comment: You're right. It's no longer so